# MySQL Trigger won't fire

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Here's the thing. My trigger works - I have tested it with simpler code. but for some reason my select statement seems to return false even though I have tested it and it is really true. Can I not include this sort of logic within a trigger or something? I have been working on this for longer than I am proud to admit and none of it makes sense anymore. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Edit: I should probably include the fact that the juiceApp db is a different db from the one that holds this trigger. But I cannot get the ID from it as it's generated in the 87586745wp db.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mysqluser`@`localhost` TRIGGER `87586745wp`.`wp_posts_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `wp_posts` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE no_data INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE email VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE user_id INT;
DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT au.UserID, au.UserEmailAddress
    FROM `JuiceApp`.`AppPreferences` ap
    JOIN `JuiceApp`.`AppUsers` au ON au.UserID = ap.UserID 
    WHERE ap.PreferenceControlID = 1 
    AND ap.PreferenceValue = 1;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR
    NOT FOUND SET no_data = 1;

SET @sub = 'Broken Glass';

-- if article part of campaign 
IF NEW.ID IN (
    SELECT post.ID
    FROM wp_posts post
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = post.ID
    INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE post.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND post.post_type = 'post' 
    AND t.term_id = 25) 
THEN
    OPEN email_cursor;
        send_email_loop: LOOP
            FETCH email_cursor INTO user_id, email;
            IF no_data = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE send_email_loop;
            END IF;
            -- record email to be sent
            INSERT INTO `JuiceApp`.`EmailQueue` (ArticleID, RecipientID, RecipientEmail, Subject)
            VALUES (NEW.ID, user_id, email, @sub);
        END LOOP send_email_loop;
    CLOSE email_cursor;
END IF;
```

END

Comment: Please add all the trigger code, including setting the delimiters , and what select are you referring to?

Comment: Are you sure that the select will return a row when the trigger runs? It only runs on insert, maybe wordpress inserts posts first as draft and changes it afterwards to published (which might be an update, not sure if wordpress stores old versions so everything is an insert). Maybe log the result of your select somewhere. Also, are you aware you do not need a cursor to do your inserts? You can simply do `insert into ... select DISTINCT new.id, au.UserID, ... FROM JuiceApp.AppPreferences ap ...`

Comment: @Solarflare I like the idea of removing the cursor. I have a cron script that runs periodically to send the emails I ended up just using that. I have narrowed the issue down to the IF statement. for some reason it returns the new.id when i run it independently but it is not returning it when used in the trigger. when I simply return the New.ID of the insert - i get two: one that matches my IF statement logic and one that does not (more of a placeholder insertion than anything). Still testing will keep this updated.

Answer (score 0):

All credit to this answer goes to @Solarflare:
I was implementing a trigger After insert - but my logic would only work on an update - as @Solarflare rightfully suggested that perhaps the statuses that I was querying was only updated after the insert. It now works fine. Thank you.